# Pass context data from generic.DetailView

Tags: python, django, generics, detailview

How can i pass the context data which is coming from a forms.py to my views class which is using generic detailView, i need to pass forms.py to my product detail page.

Here is the code for my view class

```
class ProductView(generic.DetailView):
model = Product
cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
context = {'cart_product_form': cart_product_form}
template_name = 'shopping/product.html'
query_pk_and_slug = True
```

Please let me know if this is incorrect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data), and add the form to the context before returning it.

```
class ProductView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'shopping/product.html'
    query_pk_and_slug = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
        context['cart_product_form'] = cart_product_form
        return context
```